# Is the weak convergence of the gradients sufficient for this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

I am trying to understand if
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla[\phi u + (1-\phi)u_n]|^2 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{B_2\setminus B_1} |\nabla u_n|^2
$$
up to subsequences.
Here $B_2$ and $B_1$ denote the balls of radius $2$ and $1$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$, $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(B_2)$, $0\leq \phi \leq 1$ in $B_2$, $\phi \equiv 1 $ in $B_1$, $\{u_n\}_n$ is a sequence of functions in $W^{1,2}(B_2)$ such that $\int_{B_2} |\nabla u_n|^2 \leq C$ for every $n$, and $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,2}$.

Since $W^{1,2}(B_2)$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(B_2)$, we also have $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(B_2)$. Moreover,
$$
\nabla[\phi u + (1-\phi)u_n] = \phi \nabla u + u \nabla \phi + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n - u_n \nabla \phi \rightharpoonup \nabla u 
$$
in $L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)$.

If we had $\nabla u_n \to \nabla u$ in $L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)$, the result would be true, since then the above convergence would be strong and we would have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla[\phi u + (1-\phi)u_n]|^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{B_2\setminus B_1} |\nabla u_n|^2  = \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u|^2.
$$

But is the weak convergence $\nabla u_n \rightharpoonup \nabla u$ in $L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)$ sufficient to prove the inequality at the beginning of the question?

By the weak convergence, we would have

$$
\int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u|^2 \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u_n|^2
$$
and
$$
\int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u|^2 \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla[\phi u + (1-\phi)u_n]|^2, 
$$
but this does not seem to help.

Another approach would be to observe that, for a subsequence such that the limit exists,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty } \|\phi \nabla u + u \nabla \phi + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n - u_n \nabla \phi \|_{L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)} \\
&\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \| (u-u_n) \nabla \phi \|_{L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)} +\lim_{n \to \infty}  \|\phi \nabla u + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n \|_{L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \|\phi \nabla u + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n \|_{L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)}, 
\end{align}
since $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)$.

So we are left to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n|^2 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u_n|^2
$$

Any ideas? Do you think the inequality at the beginning holds or not?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should expand the squared expression and use weak lower semicontinuity for the term containing $\|\nabla u_n\|^2$, everything else is linear in $u_n$.

Comment: also the limit on the rhs of the the inequality might not exist in general.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the comment. The limits exist for a subsequence since $\int_{B_2} | \nabla u_n| ^2 \leq C$ for every $n$ by assumption, right? That's why I wrote up to subsequences. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, right. At the end you probably want to prove that the lhs is less than $C$, which is true ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the solution.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u + (1-\phi)\nabla u_n|^2 \\
&= \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} [|\phi \nabla u|^2 + |(1-\phi)\nabla u_n|^2 + 2 \phi(1-\phi)\nabla u_n \cdot \nabla u].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now, since $\nabla u_n \rightharpoonup \nabla u$ in $L^2(B_2 \setminus B_1)$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} 2\phi(1-\phi) \nabla u_n \cdot \nabla u = \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} 2\phi(1-\phi) |\nabla u|^2.
$$
Therefore, for a subsequence such that all the limits below exist, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u + (1-\phi)\nabla u_n|^2 \\
& = \int_{B_2\setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u|^2 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1}|(1-\phi)\nabla u_n|^2 + \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1}2\phi(1-\phi) |\nabla u|^2 \\ 
& \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u_n|^2 + \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1}|(1-\phi)\nabla u_n|^2 +\int_{B_2 \setminus B_1}2\phi(1-\phi) |\nabla u_n|^2 \right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\phi \nabla u_n + (1-\phi) \nabla u_n|^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{B_2 \setminus B_1} |\nabla u_n|^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: These limits might not exist for weakly converging sequence.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the comment. We also have $\int_{B_2} |\nabla u_n|^2 \leq C$ for every $n$ in the assumptions, so these limits exist for a subsequence, right?